# phpmyadmin still accessible on /phpmyadmin after changing alias

Tags: apache, security, phpmyadmin, webserver

I'm trying to secure my web server by changing the url of phpmyadmin (/phpmyadmin).

I have edited the file /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf :

```
Alias /secure-db /usr/share/phpmyadmin
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
            AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

            php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
            php_flag track_vars On
            php_flag register_globals Off
            php_admin_flag allow_url_fopen Off
            php_value include_path .
            php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
            php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/
    </IfModule>
```

Now, I can access phpmyadmin via /secure-db, and also via /phpmyadmin

I do not understand why /phpmyadmin is still available. Of course, I did restart apache.
By the way, I'm using ISPConfig 3.0.5.4p1

Any idea? Is there another kind of vhost somewhere?

**EDIT :**
I had another file "phpmyadmin.conf.bak.20140429" in the same folder which contained the alias /phpmyadmin. After removing it I could not go to the url /phpmyadmin. So I guess that this backup file was read by apache.